# Changing JTable row to bold depending on value (using prepareRenderer)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable

So, at the moment I'm changing the colour of a whole row depending on a condition. And it's working. I'm overriding `prepareRenderer()` in a **JTable object**.

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    Component cellInTable = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    Color textColor;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers = appManager.checkNumbers();
    cellInTable.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    for (Integer no : numbers) {
        if (racesModel.getValueAt(row, 1).toString().equals(no.toString()) {
            textColor = new Color(205, 205, 205);
            cellInTable.setForeground(textColor);
            return cellInTable;
        }
    }
    return cellInTable;
}
```

However, now I want to change the font's style to **bold**. I can't seem to find how to manipulate a Component object's font. Can anyone suggest anything for me to look at? Is it possible to use HTML somehow the same way a JLabel does?

Thank you in advance

Comment: please 1. whats real goal `(... , int row, int column)`, 2. why parse put integer to XxxTableModel, 3. have to reset Color in rest of cell, 4. for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel Hi.. I really do not understand anything you're saying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found an answer!

I found that Java has a `Font` class. I used getFont() and then used setFont()!

```
Font oldFont = cellInTable.getFont();                           
cellInTable.setFont(oldFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

Hope this helps someone out there! :)